# Timepicker autoadjust position if overflows outside window

Tags: javascript, jquery, datepicker, timepicker

We're using the [timepicker](https://weareoutman.github.io/clockpicker/) for bootstrap in one of our tools. It's acting differently than how the jQuery Datepicker does when it comes to positioning itself if it overflows outside the browser window.

Datepicker will by default be below the input, and automatically set itself above the input if it doesn't have enough room below, as such:

[image: datepicker positioned above the input when input is at bottom of the page]

Timepicker does not, and half the UI is missing outside the browser:

[image: Timepicker stays at the bottom, blocking half of the UI]

What would be a good way to get timepicker to automatically position itself above the input the same way the datepicker does?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

So, without any references to the css, I can't tell you exactly what to do - but I would recommend opening up your developer tools in Chrome or Firefox and trying to readjust the values of the attributes there until u have a desired result.

If you can make an edit to your OP with some source code, or a link to the site that you are developing I could probably be more useful

Comment: Well I can make it go above the input that's not a problem, the issue is having it done automatically the same way jQuery datepicker does. I'll try and setup a jsfiddle!